# SOAP: Bad Request

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, wsdl

I am trying to access the web service. The below provided code gives the exception message: "Bad Request". Is there any way to see what exactly is wrong in my request? How to debug this code in order to see which parameters in `$p` are not correct?

```
try
{
    $webServices = $client->queryTest($p);
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
    print $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: show queryTest function..this code looks fine to me.

Comment: @Sankalp Mishra: I have only wsdl file